# Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat;

Tags: android, gradle, android-support-library

I try to update support library my application from `26.0.2` to `27.1.0` but face with below error.

#### Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'APPLICATION_ID'
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 240
        versionName "2.4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.4'
    api 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

#### Error

```
05-18 02:56:15.744 13645-13645/net.kord_music.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: net.kord_music.android, PID: 13645
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat;
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(ModelInfo.java:187)
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(ModelInfo.java:152)
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:63)
        at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34)
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:30)
        at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:25)
        at system.G.onCreate(G.java:51)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1028)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5658)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.kord_music.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.kord_music.android-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400) 
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModelClasses(ModelInfo.java:187) 
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.scanForModel(ModelInfo.java:152) 
        at com.activeandroid.ModelInfo.<init>(ModelInfo.java:63) 
        at com.activeandroid.Cache.initialize(Cache.java:66) 
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:44) 
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:34) 
        at com.activeandroid.ActiveAndroid.initialize(ActiveAndroid.java:30) 
        at com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate(Application.java:25) 
        at system.G.onCreate(G.java:51) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1028) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5658) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1637) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Comment: ListViewCompat was an internal appcompat class, don't use it. Replace references with android.widget.ListView.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I have not used it.

Comment: Checkout the stack trace. Start from `com.activeandroid.app.Application.onCreate`. In Android Studio press double Shift, type the class name and open the class. Now, in the source code, you can Ctrl+click each method call according to line numbers in the stack trace. Figure out, why the hell your DB solution thinks a private UI widget such as `ListViewCompat` is a great candidate for model. And start looking for a DB solution that doesn't let you persist UI widgets in the first place. Preferably something Android optimized, and not something that hasn't been touched for the last 4 years.

Answer (score 1):

i had same issue, solved by
**Changing every XML tag "android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat" with "android.widget.ListView"**

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/net.kord_music.android-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/net.kord_music.android-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64, /product/lib64]]`

Update your java files to

`import android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat;`

and your layout files accordingly

```
<android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat
android:id="@+id/listView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Comment: Which element must be updated to `ListViewCompat`. I do not use `ListViewCompat` in my project.