# ListViewCompat missing in android.support.v7.widget

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

Used to use [`ListViewCompat`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/9eee6ba/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat.java) as a replacement for `ListView` but after updating gradle apis it is nowhere to be found; can't even find it in the Android docs.

All I can find is a reference to [`android.support.v4.widget.ListViewCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ListViewCompat?hl=pl) which is a completely different object.

Where did `android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat` go?

Comment: can you show us your gradle properties?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
Found solution here:
[Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/widget/ListViewCompat;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50401371/failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v7-widget-listviewcompat/50403153)

> " ListViewCompat was an internal appcompat class, don't use it.
>   Replace references with android.widget.ListView. – Eugen Pechanec May
>   17 at 22:33 "

So, I just changed XML tag "android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat" to "android.widget.ListView" and it worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

ListViewCompat is an internal appcompat class,Replace references with android.widget.ListView

**Change XML tag "android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat" to "android.widget.ListView"**
It worked for me.